# Insert data from form with dynamically named fields

Tags: coldfusion, cfquery

OK. I've done a terrible job of explaining what I'm trying to do. I will try one more time to be more clear.

I have a list of variables that is submitted to a page with a `cfquery` insert. The variables come from dynamically named form fields, and are captured using a `cfloop`:

```
<cfloop list="#form.fieldnames#" index="item">

</cfloop>
```

What I have are form fields dynamically named, and a value added, as such:

```
<input type="hidden" name="ticketid_#some_number#" value="#some_quantity#">
```

For brevity, lets say the form field name is ticketid_6, and the value is 4. This could be a different name and value (for instance, ticketid_3 with a value of 1), or there might be several form fields of similar construct with different names and/or values.

So, on the insert page, I need to insert ticketid_6 4 times (creating 4 separate rows) into my table. So, a row in the database for each dynamically named form field, times the value of each.

I hope that explains it better.

Leigh,

I am still open to your suggestion on the previous post, but I fear I might not have explained my situation clearly enough for you to give your best recommendation. I will re-approach that question after I get this part figured out.

Comment: This may not apply, but ... keep in mind that any loop logic will break down if the user enters a comma into one of the fields. So be sure to handle that scenario in code (or switch to individually named fields).

Comment: @Leigh This question is related to the last question I posted, which you helped with. Thanks for that, by the way. I marked your answer as the solution. All these are hidden fields with nothing but numbers.

Comment: Okay. Looks like this structure is a little different than in the other thread. You said all of the fields have the same name. Are *all* of them really named the same ie `ticketid_6` -or- can they vary ie `ticketid_6`, `ticketid_8`, `ticketid_12`, etcetera? If so can you post a dump of of the `FORM` scope so we can see what you are working with ie `<cfdump var="#FORM#">`?

Comment: OK, you caught me. I borrowed parts of your suggestion to make this work, and subsequently decided to do it with a single form field, and capture the dynamic form field name, then the value of that form field, in an effort to simplify the flow, so to speak. They will, in fact vary, based on what the user selects two pages prior to the insert page. Do you still need that dump?

Comment: No worries. I think the other structure might be simpler but.. let us stick with your current structure for the moment. The proper handling (or processing code) really depends on the naming conventions. So yes we do need to see form field names first (obfuscate the values if needed)

Comment: @Leigh If you'd rather I do it as you suggested in the previous thread, I will make the adjustments, and move forward as suggested. I value your opinion.

Comment: Well the choice is yours, but I think the other method would be easier to parse. Store all the ticket id's in a single field named `ticket`. Store quantity in a separate field: `quantity_#ticketid#`. Then just loop through the ticket id's: `<cfloop list="#form.ticketID#" index="currTicketID"> ... grab quantity and insert </cfloop>`

Comment: Ok. I edited the question to once again to try to explain it better.

Comment: Why do you want to store `ticketid_6` 4 times - assuming form.ticketid_6 has a value of 4? That is nto very efficient database design. As @Leigh stated, storing the Id with the quantity is a single row seems like a much better idea, however, it is difficult ot say with the limited info we have.

Comment: This is an event ticket site. That said, the purchaser might buy more than one of "ticketid_6". A unique number for each ticket purchased is created and is used as a barcode to be scanned at the box office. I've already worked out the unique barcode number for each individual ticket. I just can't seem to wrap my head around how to do what I'm asking in my question.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to loop through all your field names and treat each one of those fields as a list you'd need to do two loops to insert each item.

```
<cfloop list="#form.fieldnames#" index="item"><!--- loop through all the form fields --->
  <cfif find('ticketid_',item)><!--- if the form name contains 'ticketid_'. Use findNoCase if you want to ignore case sensitivity --->
    <cfloop from="1" to="#form[item]#" index="counter"><!--- loop through the number in form.ticketid_ --->
      <cfquery datasource="#dsn#">
      INSERT INTO table (fieldname, fieldValue, TicketNum)
      VALUES (
        <cfqueryparam value="#item#" cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar">,--fieldName from the form
        <cfqueryparam value="#form[item]#" cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar">--value of the fieldName in the form
        <cfqueryparam value="#counter#" cfsqltype="cf_sql_integer">--ticket number being inserted
       )
      </cfquery>
    </cfloop>
  </cfif>
</cfloop>
```

You'll need to do server side validation to verify they haven't entered a non numeric number for the input box, but assuming you've done that this should achieve what you're looking for.

Comment: I edited my question a bit to better explain my self.

Comment: Ok. I edited the question to once again to try to explain it better.

Comment: I'm not sure what #counter# is, and why it is being inserted into the database. Also, can I insert other values using the same insert without breaking what you have here?

Comment: counter is the current ticket number being inserted. You can insert anything you want with the insert statement, why would it break?

Answer (score -2):

You need to use `Evaluate` function to get form dynamically input field value
Try this one

```
<input type="hidden" name="ticketid_#some_number#" value="#some_quantity#">

<cfloop list="#form.fieldnames#" index="item">
   <cfoutpuy>Evaluate("ticketid_#item#")</cfoutpuy>
</cfloop>
```

Comment: You can use `form[ticketid_1]` to access the value rather than using evaluate, but your loop is completely wrong anyway.

Answer (score -4):

You need to first bundle your data into an XML structure

```
<cfsavecontent variable="myFormData">
<cfoutput>
  <ul class="xoxo">
  <cfloop list="#form.fieldnames#" index="item">
    <cfloop list="#form[item]#" index="eachItem">
  <li><b>#xmlformat(item)#</b> <var>#xmlformat(eachItem)#</var>      
    </cfloop>
  </cfloop>
 </ul>
<cfoutput>
</cfsavecontent>
```

Then do a single insert

```
<cfquery>
   INSERT INTO table (formData)
   VALUES (<cfqueryparam value="#myFormData#" cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar">)
</cfquery>
```

When you pull the data, you can

- Show it as is, a bulleted list,
- Promote to a bunch of rows in a table

Note that the data is inserted as both HTML and XML

Comment: I edited my question a bit to better explain my self.

Comment: xml structure?  I don't think so.

Comment: I have created an entry on http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/37653/best-practice-for-storing-arbitrary-form-data if there are concerns about this approach

Comment: Ok. I edited the question to once again to try to explain it better.

Comment: Why would you want to turn form data into XML (or HTML)? Seems like there would be a lot of processing going to handle this, not to mention, it makes it difficult to do a proper search on database columns if it is needed.

Comment: My bulleted list has some the reasons why. But on the topic of searching, I can do a full text search on the `table` directly and it will search the entire form in one shot